# Authorization Policy argument Error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

What can I do with this:

> "Argument 1 passed to App\Policies\NotePolicy::update() must be an
>   instance of App\Note, instance of App\User given, called in
>   /Users/acny/Desktop/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php
>   on line 481 (View:`enter code here`
>   /Users/acny/Desktop/project/resources/views/notes/edit.blade.php)"

**NotePolicy.php**

```
public function update(Note $note, User $user)
    {
        return $user->id == $note->user_id;
    }
```

**edit.blade.php** (for show update button):

```
@can('update', $note)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Note</button>
@endcan
```

If I write every thing instead of 'update' in edit.blade.php then I have not error but that's not what I want.
thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies

Laravel passes the $user as the first argument.  Switch your arguments around.